# Echo out mysql into a html table?

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I need some help on how to echo out my mysql data into a html table. I'm trying to put in the relevant table tags where necessary but I must be doing it wrong as its not looking how I want it.

Here's what I am getting:

```
ID        Name      Number       Note        Alert
1
2         

Nick      Nick                   insurance       insurance      alert      alert
```

Here is how I want it to look:

```
ID        Name      Number       Note           Alert
1         Nick                   Insurance      Alert
2         Nick                   Insurance      Alert
```

Here is my code, can someone please show me where I need to put my table tags to get the desired result:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM supplier_stats") or die(mysql_error());
echo "<table class=\"table\" style=\"width:900px;  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:11px; color:#96969;\" >";

while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data))
    {
    echo "<tr><td><p>" . $info['id'] . "</p></td></tr>";
    }

?> 

<?php
include 'config.php';

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM supplier_stats") or die(mysql_error());

while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data))
    {
    echo "<td><p>" . $info['company_name'] . "</p></td>";
    }

?> 

<?php
include 'config.php';

$data = mysql_query("SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, insurance_date, NOW()) AS expire_date 
  FROM supplier_stats") or die(mysql_error()); ?>

<?php
include 'config.php';

$result = mysql_query("SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, insurance_date, NOW()) AS expire_date 
                         FROM supplier_stats") or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $days = $row['expire_date'] - 1;
    if ($days > 0)
        {
        echo "<td><p>Insurance expires in <font color=\"red\">{$row['expire_date']} day(s)!</font></p></td>";
        }
      else
        {
        $when = $days * -1;
        echo "<td><p>Insurance expires";
        if ($when > 1)
            {
            echo " in {$when} days</p></td>";
            }

        if ($when >= 8)
            {
            echo " <div class=\"green_light\"></div>";
            }

        if ($when <= 7)
            {
            echo " <div class=\"red_light\"></div>";
            }
        elseif ($when === 1)
            {
            echo " tomorrow</p></td>";
            }
        elseif ($when = 0)
            {
            echo " today</p></td>";
            }
        }
    }

?>

<?php
include 'config.php';

$result = mysql_query("SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, insurance_date, NOW()) AS expire_date 
                         FROM supplier_stats") or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $days = $row['expire_date'] - 1;
    if ($days > 8)
        {
        echo "a is bigger than b";
        }
    }

echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML

?>
```

Comment: There must be 100,000 examples of this kind of thing out there.

Comment: This is so full of duplicate spaghetti code its amazing. If at all feasible i would recommend deleting the project and starting again, in a well structured framework, having read a few good books.

Comment: to achieve this you have to change your code a lot...use your loops as nested loops then it may work...but u need to dig a lot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need more or less somethin like this:

```
    <?php include 'config.php';
     $data = mysql_query("SELECT *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, insurance_date, NOW()) AS expire_date FROM supplier_stats") 
     or die(mysql_error()); 

     echo "<table class=\"table\" style=\"width:900px;  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
     font-size:11px; color:#96969;\" >";

     while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) { 
       $days = $row['expire_date'] -1;

       echo "<tr><td><p>".$row['id'] . "</p></td>"; 
       echo "<td><p>".$row['company_name'] . "</p></td>"; 

       if ($days > 0) {
            echo "<td><p>Insurance expires in <font color=\"red\">{$row['expire_date']} day(s)!</font></p></td>"; 
        } else {
          $when = $days*-1;           

          echo "<td><p>Insurance expires";

          if ($when > 1){
              echo " in {$when} days</p></td>";
          }

          if ($when >= 8){
            echo " <div class=\"green_light\"></div>";
          }

          if ($when <= 7){
            echo " <div class=\"red_light\"></div>";
          } elseif ($when ===1) {
            echo " tomorrow</p></td>";
          } elseif ($when == 0) {
            echo " today</p></td>";
          }
        }

        echo "<tr>";
      }

      echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML
    ?>
```

Comment: thank you this has sorted the table issue and it now looks spot on, however its coming up with an error now and my code isnt working, and i cant find what the issue is.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp\htdocs\hewden_spms\alert_panel.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp\htdocs\hewden_spms\alert_panel.php on line 21

Comment: try it now, i have fixed it (I am not testing it , onle changed your code a bit)

Answer (score 0):

you've closed  after first  that is why you are getting output like this..remove  from:

```
echo "<tr><td><p>".$info['id'] . "</p></td></tr>";
```

above line...and close  after while loop ends..

Comment: I thought the same at first, but notice how he is printing all the ids together, they are gonna show up in one row.

Comment: This is only one of many many many issues. It could all be done with one sql query, but i dont think the OP will benefit from copy and pasting the answer, so i dont see the point.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Id</td>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Number</td>
<td>Note</td>
<td>Alert</td>          
</tr>
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("your query");
$i = 0;
while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data))
{
$i++
?>
<td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $info['name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $info['number']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $info['note']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $info['alert']; ?></td>       
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```